# Перенести данные из имеющихся таблиц в новую

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Столкнулся с задачей перенести данные из имеющихся таблиц в новую.

- Получаю столбцы `tmplvarid`, `contentid` и `value` , при условии, что
  `modx_site_tmplvars.name` заканчивается на `_en`
- Добавляю столбец из `modx_site_tmplvars.name` без постфикса _en
- Нужно с помощью получившегося `tmpname` с вырезанным постфиксом, добавить столбец с `modx_site_tmplvars.id` , где `tmpname = modx_site_tmplvars.name`

> ```
> SELECT modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.tmplvarid, 
>            modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.contentid, 
>            modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.value, 
>            Substring_index(modx_site_tmplvars.name, '_en', 1) AS tmpname 
>     FROM   modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues 
>            LEFT JOIN modx_site_tmplvars 
>                   ON modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.tmplvarid = 
>                      modx_site_tmplvars.id 
>     WHERE  modx_site_tmplvars.name LIKE '%_en'
> ```

tmplvarid, contentid, value, tmpname, **tmpid**

Таблица  в которую нужно перенести значения

```
CREATE TABLE `modx_localizator_tmplvar_contentvalues` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`key` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`tmplvarid` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`contentid` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`value` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Таблица из которой нужно перенести значения, где tmplvarid – это modx_site_tmplvars.id на основе name без постфикса _en

```
CREATE TABLE `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`tmplvarid` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`contentid` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`value` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `modx_site_tmplvars` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

В приведенном запросе выше, не получается повторно сделать выборку из той-же таблицы, но на основе поля с вырезанной частью строки.

UPD:

```
Таблица: modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues
INSERT INTO `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` (`id`, `tmplvarid`, `contentid`, `value`) VALUES (1, 7, 1, 'Main page');
INSERT INTO `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` (`id`, `tmplvarid`, `contentid`, `value`) VALUES (2, 7, 2, 'About us');
INSERT INTO `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` (`id`, `tmplvarid`, `contentid`, `value`) VALUES (3, 7, 4, 'Products');
INSERT INTO `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` (`id`, `tmplvarid`, `contentid`, `value`) VALUES (4, 7, 5, 'Contacts');
INSERT INTO `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` (`id`, `tmplvarid`, `contentid`, `value`) VALUES (5, 7, 6, 'News');

Таблица: modx_site_tmplvars
INSERT INTO `modx_site_tmplvars` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (7, 'pagetitle_en');
// нужно получить id в качестве доп. столбца tmpid на основе убранного постфикса _en
INSERT INTO `modx_site_tmplvars` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (8, 'pagetitle'); 
INSERT INTO `modx_site_tmplvars` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (9, 'keywords_en');
// нужно получить id в качестве доп. столбца tmpid на основе убранного постфикса _en
INSERT INTO `modx_site_tmplvars` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (10, 'keywords');
```

MariaDB-10.3-x64

Таблица modx_localizator_tmplvar_contentvalues после предполагаемого заполнения:

```
INSERT INTO `modx_localizator_tmplvar_contentvalues` (`id`, `key`, `tmplvarid`, `contentid`, `value`) VALUES (1, 'en', 8, 1, 'Main page');
INSERT INTO `modx_localizator_tmplvar_contentvalues` (`id`, `key`, `tmplvarid`, `contentid`, `value`) VALUES (2, 'en', 8, 2, 'About us');
INSERT INTO `modx_localizator_tmplvar_contentvalues` (`id`, `key`, `tmplvarid`, `contentid`, `value`) VALUES (3, 'en', 8, 4, 'Products');
INSERT INTO `modx_localizator_tmplvar_contentvalues` (`id`, `key`, `tmplvarid`, `contentid`, `value`) VALUES (4, 'en', 8, 5, 'Contacts');
INSERT INTO `modx_localizator_tmplvar_contentvalues` (`id`, `key`, `tmplvarid`, `contentid`, `value`) VALUES (5, 'en', 8, 6, 'News');
```

Comment: Добавьте пример данных (в виде INSERT INTO) в каждой из исходных таблиц (8-10 записей, длинные строки сократить до 5-10 символов), и результат НА ИМЕННО ЭТИХ данных. И на примере одной записи подробно - как она получена. И укажите ТОЧНО версию MySQL.

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте финальное наполнение `modx_localizator_tmplvar_contentvalues` в виде таблицы. PS. Почему в запросе LEFT JOIN, если он всё равно INNER? PPS. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da6fd54937dcdf3040bfc1e35c73d1ca)

Comment: modx_localizator_tmplvar_contentvalues пустая, единственное статическое значение для key = en при наполнении, все остальное из выборки.
contentid без изменений из modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues , а value при условии, что есть постфикс _en, tmplvarid = id строки modx_site_tmplvars без постфикса _en

Comment: Я понимаю, что она пустая. Какая она ДОЛЖНА СТАТЬ на этих данных, после INSERT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, задача слабопонятна, но, вероятно, требуется

```sql
SELECT modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.tmplvarid, 
       modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.contentid, 
       modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.value, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(modx_site_tmplvars.name, '_en', 1) AS tmpname,
       modx_site_tmplvars_copy.id tmplvarid 
FROM modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues 
JOIN modx_site_tmplvars 
  ON modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.tmplvarid = modx_site_tmplvars.id 
JOIN modx_site_tmplvars modx_site_tmplvars_copy
  ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(modx_site_tmplvars.name, '_en', 1) = modx_site_tmplvars_copy.name
WHERE modx_site_tmplvars.name LIKE '%_en';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50cbd191e26f24b194576fa0fafd7608)

Comment: Да все верно! Спасибо Вам огромное! Я почему-то LEFT JOIN использовал при условии ON SUBSTRING_INDEX и это выдавало ошибку, поэтому опубликовал, только с одной склейкой.

а как заполнить таблицу https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fcecf2cf447b619398457465e1538445 ?

Comment: @aliokero Гы... запрос-то правильный, а вот кавычки подкачали... [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e45c88171f2704ee21016aa298baf99f).